# SAP GUI Script - create contract headers

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I use a script for creating Contract Headers in t-code ME31K. Until some time ago it worked fine but now the script stops working when it's almost finished with creation of the contract.

Once it puts in the dummy product number, Targ.Qty, Net Price and Price Unit it gets stack on the Price. there is a message from the system saying (see second picture):

> Effective price is 1,42 SEK, material price is 0,99 SEK

I'm assuming this message didn't appear before and that's why the script stops here. If I continue manually from this step I only have to press Enter and then Save. Contract Header is created. So it is basically at the last steps that this issue occurs.

[image]

[image]

When trying the debug function it highlights in yellow below step `allowednumbers.popupdebugdialog`.

```
Public Sub AssertMessageNumbers(statusbar As SAPFEWSELib.GuiStatusbar, Optional allowednumbers As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    'Appearantly .MessageNumber is not cleared as other fields, so only check if messagetype is set
    'now we cannot disallow empty message... but for now we don't want to anyway
    If statusbar.MessageType = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsMissing(allowednumbers) Then
        For i = LBound(allowednumbers) To UBound(allowednumbers)
            If statusbar.MessageNumber = allowednumbers(i) Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    MsgBox "Unexpected message, number (" & statusbar.MessageNumber & "), text (" & statusbar.Text & "), halting!"
    allowednumbers.popupdebugdialog
 End Sub
```

---

```
    Dim row As Long, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Integer
    Dim updated As Integer
    Dim statusbar As SAPFEWSELib.GuiStatusbar
    Dim session As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSession

    ' ValidateUserOrDie

    Set session = GetSession()
    Set statusbar = session.FindById("wnd[0]/sbar")

    lastcol = Sheet2.Cells(1, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).row

    updated = 0
    For row = STARTROW To lastrow
        If Sheet2.Cells(row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone And Trim(Sheet2.Cells(row, 1).Value) <> "" Then
            Init session

            FillInitialScreen session, row
            SleepTick
            session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 ' <Enter>
            AssertMessageNumbers statusbar, Array("055")

            FillHeader session, row
            SleepTick
            session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 ' <Enter>
            AssertMessageNumbers statusbar

            FillDummyItem session, row
            SleepTick
            session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 ' <Enter>
            If statusbar.MessageType = "W" And statusbar.MessageNumber = "324" Then '
                session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 ' <Enter>, Skip past new Material Warning...
            End If
            AssertMessageNumbers statusbar

            ' fixprices h?nger scriptet...
            'FixPrices session

            SleepTick
            AssertMessageNumbers statusbar, Array("207")
            session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 ' <Enter>



            FixPartnerFunctions session, row
            SleepTick

            SaveNOutput session, row
            SleepTick
            AssertMessageNumbers statusbar, Array("017") ' Success message, create

            DeleteDummyItem session, row
            AssertMessageNumbers statusbar, Array("023") ' Success message, save

            Sheet2.Cells(row, 1).Resize(1, lastcol).Interior.ColorIndex = 35 ' Mark ID
            updated = updated + 1
            If updated >= MAXUPDATED Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question? It seems that your script does some assertions about what SAP is expected to do, but SAP may produce so many possible cases. Here, it's a functional warning. A warning is bypassed by pressing Enter. Ask the users if it's normal and what the script should do.

Comment: The question is how can I make this script work again without it being stopped. Yes it's just a warning but the script stops at this step anyway. This is what makes it so frustrating. It's only a warning but the script stops at this stage/step anyway.

Comment: The Sub is named `AssertMessageNumbers`, so I guess that it's an assertion about the current message versus the allowed messages, and it stops on purpose because the warning message number is not part of the `allowednumbers`.

Comment: You are definitely on to something here 

The Message No. of this message is 06207 when double clicking on the warning message to read more about it.

Comment: I added additional script code of the **allowednumbers** and it seems it not included. Any idea of how to include it?

Comment: The message `06207` is a unique identifier composed of the message class also known as "message ID" (`06`) and the number (`207`). By the way, I see that your script only checks the number, one day it might not work well again if you have another message like `AA207`... I see that your script handles warning messages outside `AssertMessageNumbers` (message type W, message number 324). Do the same with `207`.

Comment: Thank you it worked :) However now the script stops at: `Private Sub YesIfPopup()
    Dim button As SAPFEWSELib.GuiButton
    Set button = session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1", False)
    If Not button Is Nothing Then
        button.Press ' Save popup -> Yes
    End If
End Sub`    It says Compile error, Undefined variable :(

Comment: That should be part of another question. It's not clear on what line the compile error is (and I don't see any obvious bug).